# init @PostConstruct doesnt work

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have created a web dynamic project using **hibernate4** and **spring4**.
here are my files:

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>posts</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>users.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

---

here is the bean where I invoked `init()` method

```
package com.posts.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.posts.models.Users;
import com.posts.services.UsersService;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component("Usersbean")
@Scope("session")
public class UsersBean implements Serializable{


    @Autowired
    private transient UsersService us;
    private List<Users> lu;



    public UsersBean() {
    }



    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        lu=us.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("hello");//doesn't shw up=init() doesnt  work
    }

    public String getMyname(){
        return "mohamed";
    }
    public List<Users> getLu() {
        return lu;
    }
    public void setLu(List<Users> lu) {
        this.lu = lu;
    }
}
```

---

here is my jsp file ; I tried to show just one field:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>test list users</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="users" class="com.posts.beans.UsersBean" />
<table border="1">
<tr><th>id</th><th>nom</th><th>prenom</th><th>login</th><th>password</th></tr>
</table>

<c:forEach var="user" items="${users.lu}">
<p><c:out value="${user.nom}" /></p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

so the console doesnt show the message "hello" in method init which means that id doesnt work. 
maybe it is because that i didnt declare servlet element in web.xm, but i dont have any idea on how it works ..
NB: I tested Services With JUnit, worked fine

Comment: Why should it, you aren't using the managed Spring instance and let tje JSP create one itself. That will not work invoke (nor know anything about `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: ii m new at using jsp .. what is the solution ??

Comment: Don't user `jsp:useBean`. Use a Spring Controller to prepare your model for you.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but is there an other manipulation with modifying web.xml because ??

Comment: No. You have to use the spring managed instance, you can use the `RequestContextUtils` to get the `ApplicationContext` and retrieve the bean. But that is basically programming in the view layer which you should avoid, hence the controller with the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved that problem with annotating UserBean class with @Service("userbean") and adding :

```
<bean id="usersBean" class="com.posts.beans.UsersBean" init-method="init" />
```

in application-context.xml file ..
when I run my application , i see hibernate generated code of SELECT and the message hello

> Hello
>
> Hibernate: select users0_.id as id1_2_, users0_.login as login2_2_, users0_.nom as nom3_2_, users0_.password as password4_2_, users0_.prenom as prenom5_2_ from public.users users0_

" in the console which means that `init()` method have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work in three different ways:

1. add to your application-context.xml bean that is responsible to work out @PostConstruct annotation:

   > `<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />`
2. add namespase that already has CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor inside:

> `<context:annotation-config />`

or

> `<context:component-scan base-package="package.with.beans" /> <!-- scans components and adds <context:annotation-config /> -->`

3. define init method in the tag bean of your class for argument "init-method"